# Correct way to check for non null values in ginkgo test

Tags: go, testing, bdd, ginkgo

Suppose a function `Builder` that returns a struct like this:

```
type MyStruct struct{
      List  []OtherStruct

 }
```

I want to test the `Builder` function using `ginkgo`. I created a test suite with the following structure:

```
Describe("Builder Test", func() {
    var (
       testInstance Mystruct
       err error
    )

    BeforeEach(func(){
        testInstance, err = Builder()
    })

    It("Should not fail", func(){
       Expect(err).NotTo(HaveOccurred())
    })

    It("Should have a valid List", func(){
       Expect(testInstance.List).To(HaveLen(1))
    })

    It("Should pass some tests", func(){
       Expect(testInstance.List).To(SomeCheck())
    })

    It("Should pass other tests", func(){
       Expect(testInstance.List).To(OtherCheck())
    })

    It("Should pass yet nother tests", func(){
       Expect(testInstance.List).To(YetSomeCheck())
    })

})
```

However, if for some reason the `Builder` fails to initialize the `testInstance` correctly and the `List` field is not initialized, all the `It` tests fail with a `Panic` due to index out of bounds. As I expect the number of tests to grow, I would like to prevent this to happen.  I added the 'It'("Should have a valid List")`assertion, but this doesnt prevent the other`It` to be executed and fail.

I'm wonderting if there is an idiomatic way to add a check for `testInstance.List` to be valid before the `It` clauses that use it are executed.

Comment: Since your Builder() function return error along with the object, you should first make sure the Err is nil, before asserting anything else.
`Expect(err).To(BeNil())`

`Expect(testInstance.List).To(HaveLen(1))`

Comment: Thanks @Sheshnath, but even when this prevents the panic (and this is a huge improvement in the legibility of the test output, still I have to repeat the test on each `It`. I was wondering if there was a way for establishing a dependency or hierarchy between assertions (maybe by using contexts)  so that a "higher" level assertion if not satisfied, prevents all other "lower-level" or "dependant" assertions not to be exectued at all.

Answer (score 0):

According to [ginkgo's documentation](https://onsi.github.io/ginkgo/#extracting-common-setup-beforeeach)

> It is also common to place assertions within BeforeEach and AfterEach blocks. These assertions can, for example, assert that no errors occurred while preparing the state for the spec.